# Python - try/except method for an existing textfile

Tags: python-3.x, function, try-catch, except

For the code below, I am supposed to write three separate try/except-blocks, which react to the three following errors, respectively:

1) File is not available
2) A line in the file contains a fewer number of elements than expected
3) The user's entry cannot be found in the dictionary as a key

Also, the second error should NOT finish the program. Incorrect lines in the text-file are supposed to be skipped, so the dictionary should have three Key-Value-Pairs.
The content of the text-file looks like this. In the end, the program is supposed to be able to print both the left word(original word) and the right word (translation):

dog Hund

cat Katze

questionmark

snow Schnee

And this is the following code:

```
with open(filename, "r", encoding="utf8") as dictionaryfile:

    for line in dictionaryfile:

        elements_from_line = line.split()

        word = elements_from_line[0]

        translation = elements_from_line[1]

        translationdictionary[word] = translation

inputword = input("Welches Wort soll übersetzt werden? >")

correct_translation = translationdictionary[inputword]

print("Das Eingabewort:\t{}\nDie Übersetzung:\t{}".format(inputword, correct_translation))
```

Answer (score 0):

#### If u have to do it all in `try-except` blocks, it could look like this:

- if the file does not exist - catch `OSError`
- if a line contains in the file fewer elements than expected - catch `IndexError`
- if user *input* is not in dictionary - it means that we have to catch `KeyError`

So, after that we can try something like this:

#### Editing your code:

```
filename = 'ala.txt'
translationdictionary = {}
try:
    with open(filename, "r", encoding="utf8") as dictionaryfile:
        for line in dictionaryfile:
            elements_from_line = line.split()
            try:
                word = elements_from_line[0]
                translation = elements_from_line[1]
                translationdictionary[word] = translation
            except IndexError:
                continue  # skip line
except OSError:  # can not find file
    print('File not found')

inputword = input("Welches Wort soll übersetzt werden? >")

try:
    correct_translation = translationdictionary[inputword]
    print("Das Eingabewort:\t{}\nDie Übersetzung:\t{}".format(inputword, correct_translation))
except KeyError:  # lack of key in dict
    print('Can not find input in dict')
```